# What is the name of the most locally convex / concave point of a $f(x)$ function?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I was looking for the name given to the more locally convex / concave points of a given function $f(x)$ for instance, the ones I have marked in the multiplicative inverse function below. In the case of the multiplicative inverse it might be also a fixed point, but being a fixed point does not necessarily mean that is also locally the most convex / concave point. It is not an inflection point as well, and I am not sure if it is an stationary point, because the position is not a local maximum or minimum. So is there a name for the most locally convex / concave points of a function? thank you.

[image: multiplicative inverse]

The Wiki articles are not very clear about it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word for the measure you're looking at is "[curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)".  I'd probably call the thing you're looking for "the point of maximum curvature"; there may be a better name but I don't know it.

Comment: thank you!! so it is the point of maximum curvature.