# Finding the curvature of a line.

Tags: curves

Lets say I have a single curve segment with a known height (difference between the lowest points of the curve and the highest point of the curve)  and length (difference between the leftmost and rightmost sides). How do I find out the diameter of the circle or ellipse that would align to that curve for it's entire length?  Also how would I determine the distance from the  center of that circle to the top of the curve?  I do not know any calculus but I am pretty good with linear algebra.

Comment: Just in case, this could help, but probably you already read it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function

Comment: I know not the first thing about any of this so thanks.

Comment: Not every curve can be aligned with a circle. Unless what you're really asking is "given the width/height of a circular arc, how can I determine how big the circle it's from is?".

Comment: @LinkReincarnate it is funny because I asked something related to curvature some days ago and it was answered today... about the point of maximum curvature... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215196/what-is-the-name-of-the-most-locally-convex-concave-point-of-a-fx-function

Comment: Yes exactly Jack. That is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for  http://www.mathopenref.com/arcradius.html

The Arc Radius is what I wanted.  How do I determine the distance from the center of the circle to the bottom of the curve?  Is it just the Arc Radius minus the height of the curve?